# 今はなんでもない is asking for location?

Tags: particle-でも

The guy wakes up inside an airplane, asks 今はなんでもない (translated as: Where are we now?) and the response is above some city in Swiss.
My question is: How is this sentence transformed to a question about location?. No dictionary gives me a hint.

Comment: The translation is simply wrong.

Comment: I agree with @oldergod, but to add, while also the original Japanese sentence would often not make any sense, considering the context (saying something when waking up), the なんでもない may in this case be a way to say "never mind, I didn't say anything"; なんでもない is often used in this way, or, maybe more precisely "I already regret what I said, so even if you didn't hear it, I sure won't repeat that". Sometime also used after kindly having told something useful to a person, but realizing he/she was not listening, and then getting agry (You don't bother to listen to me, so I don't bother to repeat)

Comment: Thanks for your responses